# I need to call a phone number from my android app? Which one if efficient from the below

Tags: android, linkify

1) I have used linkify html method link

```
 value = "<a href="+to_tel+">"+number+"</a>";
 Linkify.addLinks(t, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
 Html.fromHtml(value);`
```

2) Clickable Span method

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View textView) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber.replace(" ", "")));
        startActivity(intent); 
 }


SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(stringBuilder);
spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, phoneSpanStart, phoneSpanEnd,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: You can use any one of them. I liked both.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is best which is using the intent. As it is officially recommended in [Android documentation.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Phone)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber.replace(" ", "")));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Note:**

> Places a phone call (requires the CALL_PHONE permission)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```